# How to write Javadoc for a getInstance method?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javadoc

Say I have something like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    private static MyClass sInstance;

    /**
     *
     * @return The {@link MyClass} application instance.
     */
    public static MyClass getInstance() {
        return sInstance;
    }
}
```

IntelliJ gives me this warning:

> '@link' pointing to containing class is unnecessary

What's the proper/conventional way to write this piece of Javadoc?

How would you write it?

Comment: Slightly besides the point, but unless this is just a simplified version of the real comment, I'd question the usefulness of such a Javadoc entry in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the JDK, they use `{@code}`. That does not make a clickable link, but you are already looking at the page that would be linked anyway.

For example (from [String.java](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html)):

```
  /**
  * Initializes a newly created {@code String} object so that it represents
  * the same sequence of characters as the argument; in other words, the
  * newly created string is a copy of the argument string. Unless an
  * explicit copy of {@code original} is needed, use of this constructor is
  * unnecessary since Strings are immutable.
  *
  * @param  original
  *         A {@code String}
  */
```

Answer (score 1):

You only get the warning because the link won't go anywhere. Just change it to `{@code MyClass}` to keep the formatting but without the link.

Here are some example `getInstance()` methods from the JDK.

[java.text.Collator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html#getInstance--):

```
/**
 * Gets the Collator for the current default locale.
 * The default locale is determined by java.util.Locale.getDefault.
 * @return the Collator for the default locale.(for example, en_US)
 * @see java.util.Locale#getDefault
 */
public static synchronized Collator getInstance() {
```

[java.text.NumberFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getInstance--):

```
/**
 * Returns a general-purpose number format for the current default
 * {@link java.util.Locale.Category#FORMAT FORMAT} locale.
 * This is the same as calling
 * {@link #getNumberInstance() getNumberInstance()}.
 *
 * @return the {@code NumberFormat} instance for general-purpose number
 * formatting
 */
public final static NumberFormat getInstance() {
```